# Scroll Child Recycler view along with parent scroll view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

App Hierarchy is as Follows:

- tab1/tab2/tab3/tab4 (Tab Views with ViewPagers)
- tab1 has Another tab layout with View Pagers i.e.,
- tab1--> subtab1,subtab2,subtab3(Tab Views with ViewPagers)

In tab1 I have scrollview and in subtab1 i have recyclerview.. Now when i scroll tab Tab1 the tab1 scrolls till the action bar and the subtab's action bar will stop below the first action bar and to see contents of recycler view i need to scroll it again... I do not want that to happen... i want the subtab's recyclerview to scroll continuously along with the parent scroll view in Tab1 when I swipe the Tab1...

Here is my xml for Main tab layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code for Tab1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/homeBannerSlider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    app:indicator_visibility="visible"
                    app:pager_animation="Default"
                    app:pager_animation_span="400">

                    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="#00000000" />
                </com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/speaker_image"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:background="#F7CA18" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/speaker_image"
                        android:text=" Dynamic Message........" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Latest Results" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home_Sub_TabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabTextColor="#858585"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/home_Sub_Viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is xml code for Subtab1 with recycler view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/trending_recycler_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this... Please suggest... I have tried the alternate combinations of scrollviews n nested scroll views it didnt work.. Should i Do something programatically ?? Thanks in advance